# Bike Identification needed, townie bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have a bike I purchased from a rental company about 8 years ago. It would have been three years old then, so that makes it a 2008 year bike. I could have sworn it was made by a medium end bike company, like Trek or Specialized, but I can't remember. I've also covered the bike in bumper stickers so I can't see the original graphics. I do have a logo from the front though.

[image]
It's a 24 speed but I really doubt that that matters. Here's a side view, but it just looks like a pretty generic bike to me.

[image]

I don't think it is a duplicate because I really don't care who made it, but the bike is for sale and a potential buyer may care.

This bike was rented, and later purchased, on Cape Cod, United States.

Comment: I recommend removing the stickers and then including a photo of the whole bike from the right hand side

Comment: yeah, I'm just not going to do that, because then there will be goo and I'll have to deal with that. The bikes going on Craiglist and I doubt I'll get $200, that would drop to $100 if I knew who made it and it was covered in goo... :- )

Comment: Being that I'm selling the bike it might appear snarky to a buyer who asks...

Comment: To remove the goo use Goo Gone.

Comment: Knowing the model of the bike could add value, which is why you’re asking. And if the opposite transpires, you pretend you don’t know and leave the stickers on. Meet you halfway... If you post a picture of the whole bike with stickers on and I can identify it, you send me half of the extra value?

Comment: Well that logo definitely isn't Trek or Specialized, or any of the manufacturers on that scale. As I recall, Trek's bikes are made in Taiwan and the USA, not China; I'm not sure where Specialized's non-US-made bikes are made. Is the logo instead related to the hire company? If it's the manufacturer's logo, somebody might recognize it; otherwise, we don't have enough information to go no. A photo of the complete bike would probably be useful, along with information about where in the world you are, and so on. Have you asked the hire company?

Comment: Also, note that knowing the model year really isn't going to be important to anyone. The price difference between an eight-year-old second-hand bike and a twelve-year-old one isn't going to be significant, especially compared to other factors such as the condition of the bike. Anyone who cares about, e.g., what exact componentry is installed on the bike will ask directly about that; they're not going to spend hours finding an old catalogue to figure it out themself.

Comment: Understood, I put the model year is just in case the company logo has changed!

Comment: The hire company changes bikes every three years, and they don't stick with the model. And oops, USA, New England. Yeah, I'm just hoping that someone recognized the logo, I google image searched bike logos and didn't find anything. Hey, I can try a reverse image search! Let me do that now.

Comment: Please tell me that's not a red light on the front of your bike. Red lights on the front are really dangerous: I've nearly had head-on collisions with people because I saw their red light and assumed they were moving away from me, so stopped watching them to pay attention to things that seemed more urgent.

Comment: I know that anyone that's used to left hand rear braking is going to have a nasty accident when riding it

Comment: @Dank its ok, most of the world uses their left hand for the front brake

Comment: @Swifty that's a fair point, I keep forgetting it's us Brits that are not the norm 

Comment: Interesting about the front red! Yes, I ran front and rear red flashers and a front white to illuminate the road. I think I'll take it off and update the ad. Thanks for the safety tip!

Comment: Nearest logo I could find is https://www.bicycleheaven.org/collections/antique-headbadges/products/m-w-head-badge-usa-made-never-used-cool-item-brass?variant=17011733699 which doesn't help a lot.   "MW" is also used on a number of old cars, standing for "motor works"  and "bicycle motor works" make liquid engines for bicycles.  You might get more info if you telephone the bike hire company and ask them what they remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a [Gary Fisher bike](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gary_Fisher_head_badge.JPG) to me.

[image]

If it's a 2008 then it would [have to be the Mako](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=3031147&make=682&year=2008&type=5&priceMax=20000) because all the other Gary Fisher bikes in the database have a suspension front fork. It was the cheapest Gary Fisher you could buy that year.

This particular bike came with the rare and highly coveted pig accessory.

[image]

Comment: +1 for Gary Fisher. But I'm not convinced by the 2008 Mako, it is the wrong colour, the Mako has little emblems on top of the fork legs and has 21 speeds vs our 24 I think. I have been looking on [vintage-trek](http://www.vintage-trek.com/trek-fisher-klein-lemond.htm) for an hour without any luck, take the baton and run with it ;)

Comment: I agree it may not be a 2008, that's just what Paul said in his question. I said "if" because I'm a doubter also. If we had a parts list we would stand a small chance of narrowing it down.

Comment: If you want to go further I’d ask for the wheel size, a better picture of the rhs of the bike, maybe a parts list and any items that have been changed or upgraded. But Paul is likely going to be delighted with Gary Fisher. You might come up a shortlist of where the bike name is probably located on the frame and if he’s really desperate he can remove that one sticker. This is the first ID this bike I’ve seen where the logos are present but covered with stickers... maybe because other people just remove them and have a look see.

Comment: Paul is delighted!